# Getting direct edge connections in a network graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx, network-analysis

i have the folowwing network graph:

```
import networkx as nx
net = nx.Graph()
node_list = ["Gur","Qing","Samantha","Jorge","Lakshmi","Jack","John","Jill"]
edge_list = [("Gur","Qing",{"relation":"work"}),
         ("Gur","Jorge", {"relation":"family"}),
        ("Samantha","Qing", {"relation":"family"}),
        ("Jack","Qing", {"relation":"work"}),
        ("Jorge","Lakshmi", {"relation":"work"}),
        ("Jorge","Samantha",{"relation":"family"}),
        ("Samantha","John", {"relation":"family"}),
        ("Lakshmi","Jack", {"relation":"family"}),
        ("Jack","Jill", {"relation":"charity"}),
        ("Jill","John",{"relation":"family"})]

net.add_nodes_from(node_list)
net.add_edges_from(edge_list)
```

I want to build a function that given a network, a node name, and a relationship type, returns a list of the people to which the given person is directly connected.

This is the function i got so far:

```
def get_relations(graph,node,relationship):
        if relationship == 'charity':
            charity = [ (v) for (u,v,d) in net.edges( data = True) if d["relation"]=="charity"]
            return list(set(charity))
        else:

            if relationship == 'work':
                work = [ (v) for (u,v,d) in net.edges( data = True) if d["relation"]=="work"]
                return list(set(work))
            else:

                if relationship == 'family':
                    family = [(v) for (u,v,d) in net.edges( data = True) if d["relation"]=="family"]
                    return list(set(family))
                else:
                    return None
```

calling the function like this:

```
get_connections(net, 'John', 'family')
```

yields this output:

```
['Gur', 'Samantha', 'John', 'Lakshmi']
```

This is not what i need though, i would like it to return only those people which are directly connected to John, or whatever the node is, with a direct path, not indirect ones.

Calling the function in the same way should yield this as the correct output:

```
['John', 'Jill', 'Samantha', 'Qing', 'Jorge', 'Gur']
```

---

Code attempt:

```
def get_relations(graph,node,relationship):
    if relationship not in {'charity', 'work', 'family'}: 
        return None
    relation_net = nx.Graph([(u,v,d) for (u, v, d) in net.edges( data = True)
                             if d["relation"] == relationship])

    relation_subnet = nx.Graph([(node,v,d) for (u, v, d) in relation_net.edges( data = True)
                             if d["relation"] == relationship])

    return list(set(relation_subnet.nodes))
```

However, this still returns the wrong results.

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but have you heard of `elif`? If not, you should check it out.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Your question currently bears a number of warning signs that the code snippets shown are not all from the same version of your code; it looks like you may have attempted to retype things from memory.

Comment: What do you mean by 'directly connected'? From your example, the first neighbors of 'John' are only 'Samantha' and 'Jill'...

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you for your suggestions, i fixed the incoherent parts,i will try to reformat the function in an elif form. Regarding the minimal, completeand verifiable example issue you quoted, i can't reduce it any further than it is now, with the fixes i have made, you should be able to copy and paste the code and make it run easily. I hope you can notice the problems i need help with.

Comment: @xdze2 yes but they have outgoing direct "family" connections to other people, and i need them as well

Comment: so if I understand, it is not the first neighbors but all the accessible nodes using the given edge type, i.e. for the test case all the persons reachable from 'John' using 'family' links? (on a undirected graph)

Comment: I get different output from successive executions.  Is this expected?

Comment: @Prune no it is not, are you getting different results for the same calling on the function?? It does not do that to me.

Comment: @xdze2 i need to to get the all the neighbors that have a connection for the give relation type, but only the ones who are connected with that relation type, without any other different relation type in between. So for example if i have John and Jill directly connected with family relation and Jill is connected to any other person with family relation, i need to get that other person's name. But if Jill had for example a work relation with a person, and that person had a family relation with another person, i dont need to get that.

Comment: @xdze2 it's a bit difficult to understand this problem but that's way i need to do it

Comment: @Miguel2488: yes.  I pasted your code into a text file, run it five times in a row, and get four different sets as output.

Comment: @Miguel2488, I better understand now. I think the confusion is because 'directly connected' for me means first neighbors i.e. only one edge to traverse, this regardless of the edge type. Graphs are a lot of fun and headaches, enjoy! Maybe this great course could be helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-CYnVz-uh4

Comment: @xdze2 thanks a lot for that link. i'll definitely take a good look at it :) i'm glad you understood the problem i'm trying to solve.

Comment: @Prune that sounds weird to me, did you call the function with different node names? or was it always the same? I don't know why is that happening, for me is working fine and nobody else reported a similar problem yet

Comment: I just re-ran the same code.  Yes, I'm mystified, too.  If nobody else sees it, I'll accept it as localized weirdness.

Comment: @Prune hi, i don´t know why is this happening to you, try to run the following code, it's localized at the bottom of the page in my last answers: 

`def get_relations(graph,node,relationship): if relationship not in {'charity', 'work', 'family'}: return None relation_net = nx.Graph([(u,v,d) for (u, v, d) in net.edges( data = True) if d["relation"] == relationship]) relation_subnet = nx.Graph([(node,v,d) for (u, v, d) in relation_net.edges( data = True) if d["relation"] == relationship]) return list(set(relation_subnet.nodes))`

I also invite you to read the answers at the bottom :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your coding attempt per `PMende`'s guidance is *very* close.  The problem is in your second extraction, when you try to take only those edges connected to John:

```
relation_subnet = nx.Graph([(node,v,d) for (u, v, d) in relation_net.edges( data = True)
                             if d["relation"] == relationship])
```

The selection (node,v,d) for (u, v, d) is wrong, and the condition is wrong.  In the first clause

```
(node,v,d) for (u, v, d) in ...
```

For each node in `relation_net`, you take the src, dst, and arc values ... but then discard the src and force `John` into that position.  This is valid only when `John` already happens to be the source; otherwise, you just created a new subnet edge, such as

```
("John","Jack", {"relation":"family"})  # Lakshmi removed
```

Instead, you need to keep those edges which include John in *either* position.

Second, your "relation" filter does nothing the second time; you already included every family relationship the first time.  Instead, you need to collect everyone who appears in a family edge with John.

```
relation_subnet = nx.Graph([(u,v,d) for (u, v, d) in relation_net.edges( data = True)
                             if u == node or v == node])
```

This correctly yields

```
['Samantha', 'Jill', 'John']
```

Samantha and Jill are the only direct-link family of John's.  If you want the concatenation closure on this list, then you need to iterate on the process, adding everyone new who is `family` to Jill and/or Samantha, repeating that until no new nodes are added.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Hey i really thank you for your help, i'll give this a try today and i will tell you if i got it. your explanations are good and helped see my mistakes :)

Comment: Hi again :) thank you very much for your help. I have finally made it, i got the correct solution, i will post it here now since maybe it could eventually help someone :D

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Comment: That's done buddy, i marked your answer as the correct one, is well deserved since your answer put me in the right path ;)

Answer (score 4):

First, refactoring your function definition so that it's easier to grok:

```
def get_relations(graph,node,relationship):
    if relationship not in {'charity', 'work', 'family'}:
        return None
    connections = [v for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data = True) if d["relation"] == relationship]
    return list(set(connections))
```

Then using a smaller network to test it (also to make things easier to grok):

```
node_list = ["Gur","Qing","Samantha","Jorge","Lakshmi","Jack","John","Jill"]
edge_list = [
    ("Jack","Qing", {"relation":"work"}),
    ("Gur","Jorge", {"relation":"family"}),
    ("Samantha","Qing", {"relation":"family"}),
    ("Jorge","Samantha",{"relation":"family"}),
    ("Lakshmi","Jack", {"relation":"family"}),
    ("Jill","John",{"relation":"family"})
]
net = nx.Graph()
net.add_nodes_from(node_list)
net.add_edges_from(edge_list)
```

We can see immediately that your function does not do what you're looking for:

A call to `get_relations(G, 'John', 'family')` results in the following output:

```
['Jack', 'Jorge', 'Jill', 'Samantha']
```

You have no logic for using your desired node anywhere in your code.

Really what you should be doing is:

1. Finding the subgraph of `net` made up of the edges with the correct `'relation'` attribute and all of the nodes those edges connect to (call it `relation_net`)
2. Looking for the the fully-connected component subgraph (call it `relation_sub_net`) of `relation_net` (possibly the whole thing) that contains your desired node.
3. Output the the node list of `relation_sub_net`. This is your desired output.

If you'd like to make an attempt at this, I'm sure any number of people (myself included) would be happy to help you if you get stuck.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'm new to this network thing, so i'm a bit confused about it. I will give a try at your example and i will come back to you if i have more doubts. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: this is what i've got so far:

`def get_relations(graph,node,relationship):
    if relationship not in {'charity', 'work', 'family'}:
        return None
    
    relation_net = nx.Graph([(u,v,d) for (u, v, d) in net.edges( data = True) if d["relation"] == relationship])
    relation_subnet = nx.Graph([(node,v,d) for (u, v, d) in relation_net.edges( data = True) if d["relation"] == relationship])
    return list(set(relation_subnet.nodes))`

i'm not sure if this was what you were suggesting me to do, but this is the closest i got to the desired output

Comment: calling the function now like this `get_relations(net, 'John', 'family')` yields this:

`['Jill', 'Jack', 'Jorge', 'Samantha', 'John']`

I'm doing something wrong because 'Jack' should't be there, instead, 'Gur' should be at 'Jack's place. I feel i'm very close to the result i want but i don't know where i'm getting lost. I would appreciate some enlightning here please.

thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Hi to everybody again :) I want to thank all of you for your time and help, you did help me to improve my knowledge and understanding of the problem i was facing and now i know a little more about networks. I finally got the solution i was looking for. This is how it goes:

```
def get_relations(graph,node,relationship):
    if relationship not in {'charity', 'work', 'family'}:
        return None

    relation_net = nx.Graph([(u,v,d) for (u,v,d) in net.edges(nbunch = net.nodes(), data = True) if u == node or v == node])
    relation_subnet = nx.Graph([(u,v,d) for (u,v,d) in net.edges(nbunch = relation_net.nodes(), data = True) if d['relation']== relationship])
    relation1 = nx.Graph([(u,v,d) for (u,v,d) in net.edges(nbunch = relation_subnet.nodes(), data = True) if d['relation'] == relationship])
    relation2 = nx.Graph([(u,v,d) for (u,v,d) in net.edges(nbunch = relation1.nodes(), data = True) if d['relation'] == relationship])


    return list(set(relation2))
```

I'm posting this because maybe i think it could help someone sometime. I couldn't have done it without you guys help. Thanks again :D

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond sooner! Glad you were able to resolve it.